# How to check empty array between array of objects and another array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have got a permission array of objects and groupKey.  I want to filter between permission and groupKey. if array of permission array of objects (property is empty array [] ) , then groupkey(Articles,Journals) will be removed.   For example, Here is articles and Journals is empty array[] .

```
let permission = [{
            Book: [{
                label: "Can View",
                value: "can_view"
            } ]
        },
       {
            Test: [{
                label: "Can View",
                value: "can_view"
            } ]
        }, , {
            Articles: []
        } ,{
            Journals: []
        } 
    ]

const groupKey = [    
 {label: "Book", value: "Book"},
 {label: "Test", value: "test"},
 {label: "Articles", value: "Articlefull"},
 {label: "Journals", value: "Journal"},
]
```

My accepted Output would be

```
 let groupKey = [    
     {label: "Book", value: "Book"},
     {label: "Test", value: "test"},
    ]
```

I am using filter method , but I did not get find the solution.

Comment: I've removed the functional-programming tag. In the future please do not add the tag unless you are certain you understand what it's for: people watch tags that interest them and will not be happy with you for clogging their feed with unrelated questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Object.entries` take out the `key` and the `value` of an item , check that the array is not empty using `value.length>0`then check if there is a label that matches the key if it exists push the item in the `array`

```js
  const permission = [
    {
      Book: [
        {
          label: "Can View",
          value: "can_view"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      Test: [
        {
          label: "Can View",
          value: "can_view"
        }
      ]
    },
    ,
    {
      Articles: []
    },
    {
      Journals: []
    }
  ];

  const groupKey = [
    { label: "Book", value: "Book" },
    { label: "Test", value: "test" },
    { label: "Articles", value: "Articlefull" },
    { label: "Journals", value: "Journal" }
  ];
  let NewGrpKey = [];
  permission.map(perm => {
    let key = Object.entries(perm)[0][0];
    let value = Object.entries(perm)[0][1];
    value.length > 0 &&
      NewGrpKey.push(
        groupKey.find(GrpItem => {
          return GrpItem.label === key;
        })
      );
  });
  console.log(NewGrpKey);
```

Comment: @sujon i have cleaned it up a little,  check it out

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it by using `filter` and `some` array prototypes.

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.
>
> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array
>   passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a
>   Boolean value.

```js
let permission = [
 {
     Book: [
  {
      label: "Can View",
      value: "can_view"
  }
     ]
 },
 {
     Test: [
  {
      label: "Can View",
      value: "can_view"
  }
     ]
 },
 {
     Articles: []
 },
 {
     Journals: []
 }
];

const groupKey = [
    { label: "Book", value: "Book" },
    { label: "Test", value: "test" },
    { label: "Articles", value: "Articlefull" },
    { label: "Journals", value: "Journal" }
];

const res = groupKey.filter(value => (permission.some(ob => typeof ob[value.label] !== 'undefined' && ob[value.label].length > 0)));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100% !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `reduce` method to iterate over array and check whether an object contains array which length greater than 0. And then just push the item into result array. In addition, we can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) collection to check groupKey with `O(1)`.

```
const keys = new Map(groupKey.map(l => [l.label, l]));
const result = permission.reduce((a, c) => {
    for (let key in c) {
        if (keys.has(key) && c[key].length > 0) {
            a.push(keys.get(key));
        }
    }
    return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

An example:

```js
let permission = [{
   Book: [{ label: "Can View", value: "can_view"
   }]
},
{
   Test: [{ label: "Can View", value: "can_view"
   }]
}, , {
   Articles: []
}, {
   Journals: []
}
]

const groupKey = [
   { label: "Book", value: "Book" },
   { label: "Test", value: "test" },
   { label: "Articles", value: "Articlefull" },
   { label: "Journals", value: "Journal" },
]

const keys = new Map(groupKey.map(l => [l.label, l]));
const result = permission.reduce((a, c) => {
    for (let key in c) {
        if (keys.has(key) && c[key].length > 0) {
            a.push(keys.get(key));
        }
    }
    return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic solution for any number of inputs in permission array:

(This will need type of groupKey as `var` and not `const`)

```js
var permission = [
  {
    Book: [{
      label: "Can View",
      value: "can_view"
    }]
  },
  {
    Test: [{
      label: "Can View",
      value: "can_view"
    }]
  },
  {
    Articles: []
  }, {
    Journals: []
  } 
]
var groupKey = [    
 {label: "Book", value: "Book"},
 {label: "Test", value: "test"},
 {label: "Articles", value: "Articlefull"},
 {label: "Journals", value: "Journal"},
]

permission.forEach(function(obj) {
  var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  if (!obj[key].length) {
   removeFromGroupKey(key);
  }
})


var filteredArray = [];
function removeFromGroupKey(key) {
    filteredArray = groupKey.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.label != key;
    });

    groupKey = filteredArray.slice();

}

console.log("Final groupKey ", groupKey)
```